# How to run Python script without inputting complete file path

Tags: python, file, find

I have a list that contains 2-item tuples, the Product Type and a path to a header file:

```
TypeList = [("Bed bot", "src/robot/Version/Bed/rev.h"),
               ("Tow bot", "src/robot/Version/Tow/rev.h"),   
               ("Con bot", "src/robot/Version/Con/rev.h")
              ]
```

I'm getting the usual `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory` error in terminal when I execute my complete program since I don't have the full file path to it. The full file path that would allow the program to execute would be:

```
/home/tinker1@wc.com/src/robot/Version/Bed/rev.h
```

However, when the script is run, I don't want the user to have to input the path starting with `/home/tinker1@wc.com` as this is personal information. Is there a way I can get the script to run as if I did specify the complete path?

Answer (score 1):

Use a relative path + save in a variable what you want to hide the variable

````
parent_dir = path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__))
with open(path.join(parent_dir, 'path', 'file.txt')) as fh:
    ...```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
for product,path in TypeList:
    path = '/home/tinker1@wc.com' + path
    print(path)
```

You will get the complete path printed

Answer (score 0):

Use the `os` module to get the home directory of the user.
Then join your path.

```
from os.path import expanduser, join
home = expanduser("~")
join(home, your_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try using the built-in `pathlib.Path` class for that. All you need is to prefix your paths with `~`, wrap them into `pathlib.Path` objects, and call the `.expanduser()` method.

```
from pathlib import Path
path = Path('~/src/robot/Version/Bed/rev.h').expanduser()
```

Alternatively, you can build the home path only once, and then simply use the `/` operator to join the home path with your relative paths.

```
from pathlib import Path
home = Path('~').expanduser()
path = home / 'src/robot/Version/Bed/rev.h'
```

Then you can either convert the path object back to its string representation or just use it as-is (e.g., you can use it directly for opening files with `open(...)`).